# Find Boost libraries in Makefile

Tags: c++, boost, makefile, pkg-config

**What’s the best practice for including Boost libraries in the built process?**

To illustrate, assume that our project makes use of Boost’s regular expressions and is compiled as follows:

```
g++ -lboost_regex -o main main.cpp
```

… which means that I could write a Makefile which contains just the following:

```
LDFLAGS+=-lboost_regex
```

Unfortunately, this doesn’t work on my system:

```
$ make main
ld: library not found for -lboost_regex
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Which is understandable since I didn’t specify a library path, and Boost is installed in a location where the compiler doesn’t find it.

I don’t want to hard-code that path in my Makefile, obviously. Otherwise, the project cannot be built on other machines.

One solution would be to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` but [this is discouraged](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html#AEN80).

The “real” solution for normal libraries is to use `pkg-config`, e.g. like this:

```
LDFLAGS+=$(shell pkg-config --libs sqlite3)
```

… which is resolved to something along the lines of `-L/path/to/sqlite/lib -lsqlite3`.

Unfortunately, [Boost still doesn’t support `pkg-config`](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/1094).

This leaves me in a dilemma. There doesn’t seem to be a universal way of determining the Boost library installation path. **How do other projects handle this?**

(Someone suggested the environment variable `BOOST_ROOT` but that doesn’t seem to be universally present either, you’d need to manually set it in on one of the bashrc/profile files.)

Comment: You can specify several `-L` and `-Wl,-rpath,` options and the linkers will search those in order.

Comment: @Maxim True but you’d need to hard-code paths and just guess which ones it might be. In some cases, this simply doesn’t work. For instance, I’ve got Boost installed in the path `/nfs/company_name/research/groupname/subfolder/lib` – how are you supposed to guess that path?

Comment: @Konrad: Make it a glob search for a `boost` folder! :D

Comment: @Xeo Hehe. Well, of course that fails as soon as there are more than one Boost installation (which, once again, is the case for me). You cannot even assume that the program necessarily wants the most recent Boost installation. In fact, my “true” Boost path wouldn’t be find by `locate`, necessitating a recursive search of a filesystem which is several hundred TB large.

Comment: You need to configure project. Make doesn't have configure functionality. It's are implemented by other utils. Usually, do something like configure.sh and generate makefile by template.

Comment: @Torsten That doesn’t help since it just moves the problem elsewhere. Normally, `pkg-config` does the job of finding the libraries no matter what tool you are using – *if* you know a way of doing this via, say, `configure.sh`, feel free to post the solution.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph, so there are no solution. Make doesn't have required functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I'm the one who suggested using `BOOST_ROOT`, I may aswell put it up as an answer.

Background: Boost's `bjam` build program requires a `BOOST_ROOT` environment variable if it's not executed inside the boosts installation root.
With this thought, one might aswell "rely" on it, i.e. require it to be present when `make` is invoked by either having it as a full environment variable all the time or just have it set during the session / command like `BOOST_ROOT=/foo/bar/boost make`.

Comment: It is considered bad practice for build scripts to depend on environment variables.

Comment: @Maxim Sure, *if* there is a better solution available. So far, that doesn’t seem the case.

Comment: It doesn't have to be an environment variable to make. GNU Make, for example, can take variable override values as command-line arguments.